# Can you install OSX Mavericks directly onto an external drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, installation

I have an iMac running Mavericks and I am upgrading my Macbook pro's hard drive. I have a USB3.0 mounting dock and am wondering if there is a way to load Mavericks onto that drive from my iMac so that I can then install it into my MBP and boot it either to Mavericks or to finishing the install without requiring a CD/DVD/USB stick?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. I did it with the Mavericks Developer Preview to run both OSX Mountain Lion (on my SSD) and Maverick Developer Preview on my external HDD

You can also run Mavericks **directly** from Macbook Pro using the mounting dock without any problem (provide that both your iMac and MacBook Pro are Intel based)